# does cobalt support android/windows platform

Tags: cobalt

Has cobalt already supported Android platform or even windows at current stage? If not, would you plan to complete the cobalt on the above mentioned platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Cobalt doesn't currently have Windows or Android support, and we haven't announced anything regarding these platforms.

Comment: If I check the source code of 10.58719, there are lots of  codes wrapped with  " if defined(OS_ANDROID) " as well as in gypi file such as "['OS=="win" or OS=="mac" or OS=="ios" or OS=="android" or OS=="lb_shell" or OS=="starboard"', what those stand for?

Comment: Well our code was originally branched from H5VCC, which was built for game consoles like Xbox One, and that was branched from Chromium, which has support for Android and Windows. Those ifdefs are vestigial (and should someday be removed) because now our porting is based on Starboard.

Comment: Also, I can only comment on what has been announced.